# how to make modifications to javascript code

Tags: javascript

make a select in script, from the script made

he made a script but as you can see what I can use to make boxes, I need to create a selection with options in this single script, this can be done but I don't know how to do

```js
function obtEstructuraRegistro(tablaId)
  {
    var registro = new Array();
      if(tablaId == "lista_integrantes")
    {
      registro[0] = { 'elemento': 'input',
          'type'    : 'checkbox',
          'id'      : 'marca',
          'name'    : 'marca' };

       registro[1] = { 'elemento'  : 'input',
          'type'      : 'text',
          'id'        : 'paciente[]',
          'name'      : 'paciente[]',
          'style'     : 'font-size: 11px',
          'value'     : '',
          'size'      : '15',
          'maxlength' : '20',
          'class'     : 'Fields'
            };

      registro[2] = { 'elemento'  : 'input',
          'type'      : 'text',
          'id'        : 'cantidad[]',
          'name'      : 'cantidad[]',
          'style'     : 'font-size: 11px',
          'value'     : '',
          'size'      : '7',
          'maxlength' : '3',
          'class'     : 'Fields'
            };
        
      registro[3] = { 'elemento'  : 'textarea',
          'type'      : 'textarea',
          'id'        : 'descripcion[]',
          'name'      : 'descripcion[]',
          'style'     : 'font-size: 11px',
          'value'     : '',
          'rows'      : '3',
          'cols'      : '70',
          'class'     : 'cc'
           };            
      
      registro[4] = { 'elemento'  : 'input',
          'type'      : 'text',
          'id'        : 'inicial[]',
          'name'      : 'inicial[]',
          'style'     : 'font-size: 11px',
          'value'     : '',
          'size'      : '11',
          'maxlength' : '11',
          'placeholder': '$',
          'class'     : 'Fields' };


      return registro;
    }
    return null;
  }
  function obtPropiedadesCampo(tablaId)
  {
    if (tablaId == "lista_integrantes") 
    {
      return {'class': 'celda_normal'};
    }
    return null;
  }
  function obtPropiedadesFila(tablaId)
  {
    if (tablaId == "lista_integrantes") 
    {
      return {} 
    }
    return null;
  }
```

```html
<script src="http://190.145.72.35:8080/Prueba/Prueba_SL/Js/dom_tabla-0.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://190.145.72.35:8080/Prueba/Prueba_SL/Js/lib/mootools-release-1.11.js"></script>

<form name="resformulario" method="POST" action="" id = "miFormulario" >

<table id="lista_integrantes"  border="1"  >
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>11</th>
   <th>22</th>
   <th>33</th>
   <th>44</th>
   <th>55</th>
   <th>66</th>
   <th>77</th>
   <th>88</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>


</table>


<div>
  <input type="button" value="Agregar Informacion" onclick="TDAgregarRegistro('lista_integrantes')" />
  <input type="button" value="Remover"             onclick="TDRemoverRegistros('lista_integrantes')" />
</div>
 </form>
```

he made a script but as you can see what I can use to make boxes, I need to create a selection with options in this single script, this can be done but I don't know how to do

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: When the site told you you hadn't provided enough textual explanation, the correct thing to do **wasn't** to repeat part of your text. It was to explain more thoroughly. It seems like there might be a language barrier here, can you get a friend/colleague to help you with your English or (based on your profile) try https://es.stackoverflow.com/?